# Continous delivery using Gitlab, Foreman and Puppet

Tags: puppet, gitlab, foreman, continuous-integration, puppet-foreman

We are using different tools to orchestrate our environment. On one side, we have Puppet and Foreman to deploy our different server applications, on the other side, we are using Gitlab in order to manager issues, integrated with the Git merge requests. We have a Gitlab pipeline running tests.

We would like to improve the integration and be able to deliver our server applications on all our servers from Gitlab. How could it be done? Can we chain the process from Gitlab to Foreman to the Puppet nodes? Or is it better (and possible) to launch the Puppet deployment directly from Gitlab?

Comment: Things evolved, and we think about getting rid of Foreman (but keeping Puppet). What's the easiest way to run a Puppet deployment from Gitlab CI?

Comment: I found this, but I don't know if it's production ready. https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppet/gitlab_ci_runner/readme